# OF-B1 report - cell A1

Tags: solvency-ii

Pretty basic question - what is the SIGN that should be used in cell A1 of the EIOPA Solvency II OF-B1 report?  So should share capital be displayed with a positive or negative value?

CP-13 extract:

[image]

As this wasn't clear from the LOG file..

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about financial accounting.

Comment: The question relates to a QRT cell defined under pending Solvency II regulation applicable to European insurance companies.  It is neither GAAP nor IFRS.  Do Solvency II related questions belong on a different stackoverflow site?